# Add new element to Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert array element where Title is 'Cities' but it either doesnt insert or inserts in new array not Links.Link. Any Idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried push and $addToSet

```
{
    "Component" : [
        {
            "Title" : "regions",
            "Links" : {
                "Link" : [

                    {
                        "Text" : "Tyrol",
                        "Url" : "/1xf-en700p/cheap-holidays-tyrol",
                        "Title" : "Cheap holidays Tyrol"
                    },
                    {
                        "Text" : "Browse Regions ",
                        "Url" : "/1xf-en6ujz-10ts/cheap-holidays-austria/regions",
                        "Title" : "Cheap holidays Austria",
                        "Style" : "BrowseForMore"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {

            "Title" : "cities",
            "Links" : {
                "Link" : [
                    {
                        "Text" : "Maria Saal",
                        "Url" : "/1xf-enu4dl/cheap-holidays-maria-saal",
                        "Title" : "Cheap holidays Maria Saal"
                    },
                    {
                        "Text" : "Nessendorf",
                        "Url" : "/1xf-enwvu8/cheap-holidays-nessendorf",
                        "Title" : "Cheap holidays Nessendorf"
                    },

                ]
            }
        },

    ],
    "Id" : "125570",

}

with 

var pd = { Text: 'test',Url: 'test',Title: 'test' };
db.PopularDestinationsUk.update
( 
    {
         Id: '125570'
        ,'Component.Title': 'cities'}

    }
    ,
    { 
        $push: 
        {
            'Component.Link.$.Links { Text: 'NEW',Url: 'NEW',Title: 'NEW' }}}
        }
    }
)
```

but it doesnt insert into right place

Answer (score 1):

Update your query as follows :

```
db.PopularDestinationsUk.update({Id: "125570", "Component.Title" : "cities"}, {$push : {"Component.$.Links.Link" : {Text: 'NEW',Url: 'NEW',Title: 'NEW'}}})
```

Comment: Wow that was quick and it worked. Thanks, I have been trying to figure it out for ages